# Get value using lxml

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, lxml, lxml.html

I have the following html:

```
<div class="txt-block">
<h4 class="inline">Aspect Ratio:</h4> 2.35 : 1
</div>
```

I want to get the value "2.35 : 1" from the content. However, when I try using lxml, it returns an empty string (I am able to get the 'Aspect Ratio' value, probably because that is neatly between tags.)

```
item.find('div').text
```

How would I then get the "2.35 : 1" value? Using `etree.tostring` does get me the full output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the `.tail` of an element:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

data = """
<div class="txt-block">
<h4 class="inline">Aspect Ratio:</h4> 2.35 : 1
</div>
"""

root = fromstring(data)
print root.xpath('//h4[@class="inline"]')[0].tail
```

Prints `2.35 : 1`.

As an alternative, you can get the *following text sibling* of the `h4` element:

```
root.xpath('//h4[@class="inline"]/following-sibling::text()')[0]
```

Also, make sure you are using [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) since you are dealing with an HTML data.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.text_content()`, instead of `.text`, which will give you the entire text contents of the element (http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) --

```
>>> item.find('div').text.text_content()
Aspect Ratio: 2.35 : 1
```

The full statement would then be:

```
>>> title_detail.text_content().split('Aspect Ratio: ')[1].strip()
2.35 : 1
```